# Trying to search through a string with a start and end point

Tags: vb.net

I need to search through some strings and look for a certain area to start and to go until it finds the end point, the distance between the two points will vary throughout strings so I can't used something length based

Here is an example of one of the strings I would be looking for

```
IF (SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4) >= '1900' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4) <= '2999' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2) <= '12' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2) >= '01' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2) <= '31' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2) >= '01',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4),'-',SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2),'-',SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2)))"
```

The start point I want to use is "IF (SUBSTRING(" and I want the end point to be "7,2)))" since those two always remain consistent. How would I do this?

Comment: You should look at the `DateTime.Parse()` family of functions, maybe in combination with a _regular expression_.

Comment: If you want to exclude the start/end points, Regex it as, e.g., `^IF \(SUBSTRING\((.*?)7,2\)\)\)$`. But, since it appears your start/end points have fixed lengths, it's not clear what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the indexes of the start point and end point and use them to get the substring from the search query.

You can use something like this.

```
' stringToSearch is the value you want to search
    ' 
    Dim stringToSearch As String = "<SomeText>IF (SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4) >= '1900' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4) <= '2999' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2) <= '12' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2) >= '01' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2) <= '31' AND SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2) >= '01',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,1,4),'-',SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,5,2),'-',SUBSTRING(A.DATE_QUOTE_CNV,7,2)))<SomeText>"

    Dim startPoint As String = "IF (SUBSTRING("
    Dim endPoint As String = "7,2)))"
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    If stringToSearch.Contains(startPoint) And stringToSearch.Contains(endPoint) Then

        Dim startIndex = stringToSearch.IndexOf(startPoint)
        Dim endIndex = stringToSearch.IndexOf(endPoint)

        ' search result
        result = stringToSearch.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endPoint.Length)

    End If
```